# Trigger not firing from external system (SAP)

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am trying to invoke a trigger for a object after insert but that is invoking fine when I am trying to update object for updating from `salesforce UI`  but `not working` when data is coming from the external system (SAP).

The code which i m trying :

```
trigger Trigger on obj1(after insert,before update,before insert,after update) {
ObjHandler objHandler = new ObjHandler();


if(Trigger.IsBefore || Trigger.IsUpdate)
{
   objHandler.beforeInsertUpdate(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the data is inserted from SAP to SFDC?

Comment: we are sending data from SAP through PI and we have passed the standard object in PI .

Comment: can i know the code of beforeInsertUpdate ()?

Comment: Problem is trigger is not firing and its not going inside beforeInsertUpdate

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is caused by he structure of your trigger's code. See below for how it needs to be modified, which assumes all `before triggers` go to the same before handler and all `after triggers` go to the same after handler:

```
trigger Trigger on obj1(after insert,before update,before insert,after update) {
    ObjHandler objHandler = new ObjHandler();


    if(Trigger.IsBefore{
       if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
           objHandler.beforeInsertUpdate(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
       }
    }
    else if(Trigger.IsAfter{
       if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
           objHandler.afterInsertUpdate(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
       {
    {

}
```

I'll add that the `if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)` is superfluous and can be removed in both of situations above. However, if you need to separate them out and send the `isInsert` or `isUpdate` to different handlers, then you'll want to have `if` statements to determine which handlers they go to.